# Create a list of arrays using Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, logic

Around one year ago I started to write my first application in PyQt5, where there are many fields:
[image]
I know it's not good-looking, but the main point was to learn PyQt5.
Now I want to make it useable on mobile. Since there are many people after IT studies knowing Java, I think I have a better chance to get the first job knowing Django + Javascript/jQuery. Here is the question:
Each "F1, F2, F3" is a separate widget. The screen on a phone is small, so I think about displaying them one by one. Easiest approach is probably this way (.html), but maybe there is a better one:

```
{% for field in GoldArrays %}
<p>{{field.text}} <input type="number" name="textfield"> {{field.number}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It's for F3/F4 widget. 'text' will return 200zl, 100zl, etc, number is just a DecimalField.

The thing is I'm very fresh to web development and Django. As I understand I should create a separate template for each widget. I want to collect data from a widget after pressing "next" button and then store it to SQLite database, so the progress will be saved. Should I put sql queries in views.py? What should be in forms.py and models.py? An example of two user inputs is highly appreaciated.

Here is the next question... There is a decent chance, that I'll want to set some rules for many fields, like highlighting value so the user doesn't need to delete the value, or to automatically set 0 in case there is None as input. I know I can do that with JS later, but can I do it with Django? I hope to write a code, that is easy to maintain.

Help please :)

Answer (score 0):

Using views (controllers in Django) you can add context data.

It has next structure:

```
{% for item in form_set %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Jinja2 is templating language, so all vars from backend you must write in brackets

> {{ each_var_from_django }}

View will be next:

```
class CreateOrderView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('namespace:url')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['form_set'] = Model.objects.filter()
        return ctx
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. It's not what I asked for, but still useful :)
I was writing and thinking that samle code, that's why one variable didn't have `{{}}`. To tell the truth, name should probably change too so it'll be easier to use JS. It's everything in design.
You are using CreateView and get_context_data here. I was thinking of using `if form.is_valid():
    subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']`
It's clearer for me as I get separate value from each field, I may store each widget in one list. Any reason to do it 'your way'?

Comment: I think you should use different integer fields in your django models. And U can separate them my class (subject, you want) and next use it in Jinja.

Comment: Can you give an example? I know I need to separate them, but as I said I'd like to be able to change some properties of many fields in just one line. There are over 100 fields. For example I'd like to set default value to zero. It would be nice to just iterate over all fields and this way set attribute to all of them.

Comment: Different integer fields? Any ideas? I used DecimalField and simple number input, where I'll add restrictions later. Again, it would be nice to set restrictions with Django, I don't know how to do that with user input.